# Why my wcf service request headers always get

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config

Work on wcf project,my service request headers why always become get ,even I request for post.

Bellow is my fiddler out put

My **post** request

[image]

**result 302 responce**

[image]

**result 405 responce**

[image]

What to do? why my service behave strange way?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, is it possible that the GET request is generated due to the redirection occurred and the request gets redirected to a url that only accepts POST?? then this might be a case as redirection is GET in nature.

Comment: @ SamGhatak,yah you are right.After redirect to a url that accept only post.In this situation what to do.

Comment: That's difficult to suggest from the data pointers we have here. From fiddler can you hit the second url directly with POST method?

Comment: with out redirect, if i directly call my service by post  request in fiddler then it's work perfectly

Comment: So I guess its solved?

Comment: @ SamGhatak i need to redirect,as my service is very old we need to shift in new domain,those who use my old domain they can also capable to access this service.so redirect is mendatory.what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the redirection from the first url. Redirected requests are GET by nature and here the redirection is targeted to a url that accepts only POST. In this case hitting the second url(the redirection target) using POST method solves the problem.

Now, as you say redirection is mandatory, one way to do that is to make the new URL allow GET and pass a encrypted token containing the useful parameters as a query string parameter. This way you can get both: 1. encryption makes the second url secure and 2. you can pass the parameters to the new url without exposing them in the query-string.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your response,problem is it's a old service as i tell you already.It's horrible to change any code in existing services,hope you understand.we just change the domain not any modification or extension.is there any way to do that.

Comment: @shamim : I understand, but to get the flexibility of the users requesting the older URL with some data getting redirected to the new URL with same data, some modifications will be required. I absolutely agree its really risky to start some new implementation on old services, but I am not sure if it can be done without any significant changes.